# Stop the setrepeat of Android alarmmanager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have created the alarm as shown below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Areceiver.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1234567, intent, 0);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timenow, 3000, sender);
```

I created a button to stop the alarm. In the onclick method i have written the following code

```
Intent intentstop = new Intent(this, Areceiver.class);
PendingIntent senderstop = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
            0, intentstop, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManagerstop = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManagerstop.cancel(senderstop);
```

But the job is not stopping.  What might be the issue?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You gave your Pending intent a request_code = 1234567 when you start the alarm. But you are using 0 when you try to stop it. Use this when trying to stop and should work

```
Intent intentstop = new Intent(this, Areceiver.class);
PendingIntent senderstop = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
            1234567, intentstop, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManagerstop = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManagerstop.cancel(senderstop);
```

Comment: This helped me too. Although, my intenet started a service so instead of using PendingIntent.getBroadcast, I used PendingIntent.getService.
Thanks!

Comment: Is there any method that is guaranteed to be called on the service? Unfortunately `onDestroy` is not called in my case