# How to stop a service at a specific time of the day?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio, android-service

I have been able to start a service at specific time of every day but I want to do the exact same thing to stop but I don't know how.

---

Here is the code I use to start the service using AlarmManager.
note: I am new to android dev so providing a full commented code will be highly appreciated.

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Service.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389143/stop-the-setrepeat-of-android-alarmmanager

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Service can be stopped from any running class provided you should have the context.
From the following steps you can stop the running service at specific time using **[Receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html)**.

**1. Create a [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26380942/4491620) class in your application.** On receive action check if service is running or not,if running stop using **Context**.

```
public class TestReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("STOP_TEST_SERVICE")) {
        if (isMyServiceRunning(context, TestService.class)) {
             Toast.makeText(context,"Service is running!! Stopping...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             context.stopService(new Intent(context, TestService.class));
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Service not running",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context context,Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

**2. Register the receiver in AndroidManifest.**

```
<receiver android:name=".TestReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="STOP_TEST_SERVICE" />
            <action android:name="START_TEST_SERVICE" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**3.Create a [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html%22PendingIntent%22) with desired action, then set scheduled action using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) in your activity class.**

```
 public void setStopServiceAlarm() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            new Intent().setAction("STOP_TEST_SERVICE"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarm.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

***Hope this helps!!***

Comment: works like a champ ! you deserve 50 points ;) but may I ask you how did you learn java specifically on android platform because I am a beginner and honestly I don't know where to start learning  !

Comment: @Mouyahama, I started learning android from "thenewboston" video series( Link: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A ). And you can start with basic app, Ask any question on stackoverflow most of the basic questions related to android are already answered here.Also checkout Vogella android tutorials (Link: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/android.html ). Thanks for accepting my answer.{EnjoyAndroid}

Answer (score 2):

In the same way.

When you launch a `Service` with an `Intent` (or through a `PendingIntent`) Android start the service if needed, will call `onCreate()` if that's the case, then the `onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)` method passing the `Intent` and a `startId`.

The `Service` is supposed to manage its own lifecycle and call `stopSelf()` when it's done, when the service is destroyed by Android the `onDestroy()` method is called.

The only other way of starting a Service is **binding** to it from an `Activity`. This does not trigger a call to `onStartCommand()`, it calls `onBind()` instead.

Android terminate the service if

- the service call `stopSelf()` and there is no `Activity` binded to it
- the service is unbinded from an Activity, there are no other bind nor other commands for which the `stopSelf()` has not been called
- low resources on the device (this is where the `START_STICKY` flags and those kind of flags comes into play)

The `stopSelf()` method has a `stopSelf(int)` version. Calling it without parameters means: *I'm done with all, stop me*; calling it with the integer means: *I'm done if no other command has been received after this one*; the integer is one of the `startId` you get in `onStartCommand()` method. If you have a queue of operation running one after the other it is natural to call `stopSelf(int)` after each operation has run, otherwise your `Service` need to know when to call stop.

So usually a `Service` should "know" what it is doing and stop itself when its done but you can launch an `Intent` with a specific action (say `"ACTION_STOP")` for that `Service` and handle that action calling `stopSelf()`. If it was running this will stop it (your responsibility to close any background thread / release any resource, maybe in `onDestroy()`). If it wasn't running it will start and immediately stop.

That said I invite you to think about what you are doing. You didn't specified but your request is a bit weird, I can't think of a reason why a service shutdown should be scheduled.

Finally, consider having a look at `JobScheduler` for Lollipop and later. It's better for battery usage.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Daniele- your service should know when to stop itself and stopping it on a timer is strange. That said, to stop a service at a specific time each day you could simply send in an extra to your Service. When the Service sees the extra, it knows to stop.

Using what is essentially your code,

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // set the time when youre supposed to stop
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Service.class);
serviceIntent.setAction("stop");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0,
        serviceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

and in your service's onStartCommand you simply do something like

```
public void onStartCommand()
 {
 if("stop".equals(intent.getAction))
 {
    stopSelf();
    return;
 }
 else {
    // do whatever you were doing 
 }
 }
```

Try to use constants instead of a literal like "stop", though since that's good practice.

Comment: when I start the service the app crashes here is my service onstartcommand https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a27dd9d91c59a731c14a

Comment: And in my MainActivity I included your code to be executed on buttons click : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a9255c64b540e15f099c

Comment: What crash do you get? It'd help if you could post the stacktrace!

Comment: here is the logcat when the app crashes : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cebd58a1c283cfa84f54

Answer (score -3):

How I stop a service.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getAppContext(), MyService.class);
 getAppContext().stopService(intent);
```